# Problem with MSAL scopes (NodeJS serverside web-app)

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-ad-msal

Strugging with defining scopes for MSAL authentication for my Node.js app.

I have followed this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/node

This is the config:

```
OAUTH_APP_ID=******************************
OAUTH_APP_PASSWORD=******************************
OAUTH_REDIRECT_URI=http://localhost:3000/auth/callback
OAUTH_SCOPES='profile user.read api://******************/widget.read'
OAUTH_AUTHORITY=https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations
OAUTH_ID_METADATA=v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration
OAUTH_AUTHORIZE_ENDPOINT=oauth2/v2.0/authorize
OAUTH_TOKEN_ENDPOINT=oauth2/v2.0/token
```

It want a token for both API and MS Graph, however MS Graph is not so important. Has anyone experienced the same? Because it's now only giving me a token that works for MS Graph

Comment: Please let us know which API you are using?

Comment: Please refer to this [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-javascript-nodejs-webapi-v2) For Expose API using node js.